# Android Game Loop vs Timer

Tags: android, loops, timer

I am working on an Android game, and I've noticed that a lot of tutorials talk about **Game Loop**. On the other hand, I've followed other tutorials that achieved the same result as Game loops with a different approach, using a **Timer**.

**Why is there a need for game loops when you can just use a Timer?**

Here is the code I used with timer.

```
    private final static long Interval = 30;

    GameView gameView = new GameView(this);   //Custom View

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    gameView.invalidate();
                }       

            });

        }       

    },0, Interval);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no difference for simple games. Because GameLoop is actually timer implementation.